# Packing a system daemon on Mac with CPack

Tags: macos, cmake, cpack

I am trying to create a system wide service on Mac using CMake for build and CPack for generate a package. The repository is quite big, so I have created a smaller version to test it. It turns out that I don't know how to pack something that have an absolute path as a destination.

This is the CMake code:

```
install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/hello
        DESTINATION "/var/local/hello"
        COMPONENT TS
      )

install(PROGRAMS com.hello.world.plist
        DESTINATION "/Library/LaunchDaemons/"
        COMPONENT TS
      )
```

And this is the output from cpack

```sh
mac-mini-2:build melanoholly$ cpack ..
CPack: Create package using productbuild
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: testingPack
CPack: - Install project: testingPack
CMake Error at /Users/salvobit/sandbox/cpack-example-mac-daemon/build/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /var/local/hello.  Maybe need administrative
  privileges.


CMake Error at /Users/salvobit/sandbox/cpack-example-mac-daemon/build/cmake_install.cmake:56 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/Users/salvobit/sandbox/cpack-example-mac-daemon/com.hello.world.plist" to
  "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hello.world.plist".


CPack Error: Error when generating package: testingPack
```

If I run `cpack` as root the generated package is empty.

Can somebody give me and idea how to fix this?

I use CMake of version *3.13.0-rc2*.

Comment: As far as I know, CPack doesn't like **absolute** installation paths. Do not use absolute paths in *DESTINATION* option for `install` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this was specifying the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as that

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/")
```

When you do it like that you can install path in `/var/` as

```
install(PROGRAMS <binary>
        DESTINATION "../var")
```